# How to use Windows Authentication for intranet website?

Tags: asp.net, windows-authentication, web-deployment, intranet

I'm developing Asp .Net(MVC3) web application for my company.Some users use this site in internal network and some will use internet site.I've to Authenticate Users using the website.How can i do it?
Whether it is possible to check the Authentication code only after deploying the Solution? How can i check it in my local solution?Can Anyone Explain Step by step Process involved in this?

Comment: Your company is running active directory, and the users will be using their AD credentials for both internal AND external access?

Comment: Not clear - the title is about "intranet website", in the question your ask about "website" - do you mean intranet or internet?

Answer (score 0):

Its hard to give you a step by step procedure given that I don't know much about your infrastructure, or your dev environment.

With that said, it sounds like you want forms authentication for your external site, and integrated authentication for your internal. In both cases, the back end authentication would be done by Active Directory. A VERY common scenario.

All you need to know is the right terms to use, and you'll quickly find examples online. Google up something like "mix form and windows authentication mvc". But again, given all the different versions of IIS and MVC, there are quite a few scenarios so you may not find a definitive guide and instead you'll have to wind up evaluating each and mashing up a solution for your environment.